# Django: how to use helper function to get model object if exists?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am having this model which is conversations related to ads in classified ads website:

```
class Conversation(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ad, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='starter', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User) 

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('messages-conversation', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def get_if_exists(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

in the view I want to check if conversation about that ad already exists with `get_if_exists`, but I get the errors:

1. If use

   `conversation = Conversation.get_if_exists(ad=ad, starter=request.user)`

   I get

   `Exception Value: name 'self' is not defined`
2. If use

   `conversation = Conversation().get_if_exists(ad=ad, starter=request.user)`

   gets:

   `Exception Value:   Manager isn't accessible via Conversation instances`

What I am doing wrong? How to make it so I can use one line in the view to get object if exist and None if doesnt exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a [**`@classmethod`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod):

```
class Conversation(models.Model):

    # …

    @classmethod
    def get_if_exists(cls, **kwargs):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except self.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

here the first parameter `cls` is a reference to the class object. You can then call this with:

```
Conversation.get_if_exists(ad=ad, starter=request.user)
```

This also makes the manager `.objects` accessible, since we do not use a `Conversation` *object* but the conversation class. Furthermore if you inherit the conversation in a subclass, it work with the subclass if you call it with `SubclassOfConversation.get_if_exists(…)`.

Comment: Because of you now I have also learned about custom Managers!